# Maximum value secondary index key's in DynamoDB with single table?

Tags: java, c, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with primary key but how much maximum secondary key's i use in that table?

Answer (score 2):

You can define up to `5` local secondary indexes and `5` global secondary indexes per table. [Limits in DynamoDb](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html)

.

Comment: Thank you :) for your ans but i want the exact number in secodary keys in master table. i am new in DynamoDB.